# Expanding ArangoDB into multiple storage drives

Tags: arangodb

I have a Vultr server with 2 block storages drives (mounted as explained here: https://www.vultr.com/docs/attaching-block-storage)  but my concern is how would I get ArangoDB to not store ANY data on the default server drive and instead store the data on Block Storage #1 and when its filled, use Block Storage #2.

The reason I ask for this is that there is a hard limit of 10TB per Block Storage instance so therefore if my data is larger than 10TB, my only option would be to store it in another drive.